# Using Bootstrap, I Need To Replace The Order of My Divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap code is as follows.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-8">
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need help on creating a CSS media query to position col-sm-4 to be on top of col-sm-8 on mobile phones. Thank You!

Comment: have you done any research before posting your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Reordering classes to do this. See the [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering).

See working example Snippets

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h3>With Reordering</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="alert alert-warning">UPPER 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">LOWER 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8">


      <div class="alert alert-info">LOWER 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-4">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">UPPER 2

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <h3>
    Without Reordering
  </h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="alert alert-warning">UPPER 1
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">LOWER 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">UPPER 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="alert alert-info">LOWER 2

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem and if your question is answered please mark it as closed.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Tried that, the order is as previous.

Comment: Should work in the first row. In the second though, the 1/3 column must be on the far right on desktop?